# How to manipulate an integral that contains a matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have the following integral (https://xiuming.info/docs/tutorials/reml.pdf page 6):

$$ \int f_{x}([A,G]^{\top} x|\beta,\theta) d\beta
 $$

Since $[A , G]^{\top}$ is a constant, can it be removed from the integral and thus re-written as:

$$\frac{1}{\det([A,G])} \int f_x(x|\beta,\theta) d\beta$$

**Is there some law in Matrix Algebra which states that when you have a matrix of constants in an integral, this matrix can be removed from the integral by writing the  reciprocal of the determinant of this matrix?**

Can someone please show me how this was done?

Thanks!

Comment: A change of variable introduces the determinant of the associated Jacobian matrix.

Comment: @ A rural reader: thank you for your reply! If you have time, could you please further walk me through this? Thank you so much!

Comment: [A bit of info](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Multiple_Integration/15.07%3A_Change_of_Variables_in_Multiple_Integrals)

Answer (score 2):

The "Law in Matrix algebra" you are looking for is simply integration by substitution.

On page 5 we see that
$$y(\beta) = X\beta + \epsilon$$
Call $[A,G]^T = M$.

This means that the function $f_y(My|\beta, \theta)$ can be written as $f_{y}(M(X\beta + \epsilon)| \theta) = f(My(\beta))$. Now looking at the integral,

$$\int f(M(X\beta + \epsilon)) d\beta $$
In the 1D case, for $M>0, X\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ we can see that, letting
$$M(X\beta+\epsilon) = X\tilde\beta + \epsilon \qquad \text{which gives}\qquad MXd\beta = Xd\tilde\beta$$
And so integrating by substitution ($M>0$ so our limits remain as $-\infty$ to $\infty$),
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(M(X\beta + \epsilon))d\beta = \frac{1}{M}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(X\tilde\beta + \epsilon)d\tilde\beta = \frac{1}{M}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y(\beta))d\beta$$

If we had that M<0, we would need to swap the limits back to being from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ which would give us a negative sign in the front, leading to $1/|M|.$

In higher dimensions, instead of having $|M|$ as the length scaling factor, we have $|\det M|$ as the volume scaling factor, and so we get a similar result (take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables if you need a refresher on higher dimensional integration by substitution).

$$\int g(y(\beta)) d\beta = \int g(y) \left|\det\left(\frac{d\beta}{dy}\right)\right|dy = \int |\det X^{-1}|g(y)dy$$
Where we have used the definition of $y$. Thus,

$$\int f(My(\beta))d\beta = \int |\det X^{-1}|f(My)dy$$
and applying integration by substitution again, this time on $My$
$$ = \int \frac{|\det X^{-1}|} {|\det M|}f(y)dy = \frac{1}{|\det M|}\int f(y(\beta)) d\beta$$

Hope this helps!